# OpenShift: namespaces is forbidden: User <user-name> cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group at the cluster scope

Tags: openshift

I've created a new user and assigned it admin role to one project.

I'm running some code that tries to deploy to that project, however I get this:

```
namespaces is forbidden: User <user-name> cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group at the cluster scope
```

How can I add this role to this user?

I tried doing this:

```
# oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user namespaces my-admin
Warning: role 'namespaces' not found
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/namespaces added: "my-admin"

# oc adm policy add-role-to-user namespaces my-admin
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/namespaces added: "my-admin"
```

They don't seem to have any effect.

Using OpenShift 4.2

Comment: Namespaces is cluster wide objects so you have to provide cluster wide role to user, e.g. cluster-admin https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/additional_concepts/authorization.html#cluster-and-local-rbac

Comment: @Oligzeev So just to list namespaces I need a cluster-admin role? Or is there a more granular, direct ClusterRole that I could use?

Comment: Try listing projects. OpenShift organizes things around projects vs namespaces in Kubernetes. ```oc get projects```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/additional_concepts/authorization.html#roles)'s list of default roles and overview about roles. You can check role's posibilities via:

```
oc describe clusterrole.rbac
```

It returns list of available roles with assigned verbs. For instance, there's cluster wide role 'cluster-reader' with following verbs on namespaces which is can be used to list namespaces:

```
namespaces  []  []  [get list watch]
```

Comment: so why do you think this command failed? `oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user namespaces my-admin`

Comment: Because there's no such role 'namespaces'. Namespace is a resource in terms of roles

Comment: You're killing me man. What is the command I need to run to give my user access to namespaces get/list without making the user a cluster-admin? That's what I'm after!

Comment: To list namespaces: oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-reader my-admin